# Why did they give Clara hacker powers?

Tags: doctor-who

Dr. Who Season 7, Episode 6 (The Bells of Saint John), the one where there's something malevolent in the Wifi: why did the bad guys give Clara hacker powers?

I get to watch Dr. Who in dribs and drabs, usually woefully out of date and out of order, which means there are usually details that I'm somewhat puzzled about. However, this time I did manage to watch the other two Clara Oswald episodes *before* I watched this one, so at least I knew why the Doctor was going on about governesses. However, I don't understand why the bad guys (and forgive me if they have a name: I missed it) decided it was a good idea to give Clara hacker abilities while they were downloading her. As far as I could tell, the downloaded people don't actually *do* anything, other than try to tell everyone that they don't know where they are. So what purpose would it serve to enhance their knowledge?

(I also don't quite get why they'd give her the enhancement first, before completing her download? Why incur the extra bandwidth, if you can call it that in this case? Or maybe that's not what happened, but then why did Clara have the abilities after the Doctor interrupted that first download?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the start of the episode, someone trapped in the Wi-Fi gives a warning. In the warning, there is this part:

> They can see you. And if they can see you, they might choose you.

So, before downloading people, they carefully select them. Just before they download Cara, 
Alexei and Miss Kizlet had this exchange:

> **Alexei**: We've got a positive lock on her, but I think she's borderline. Very clever, but no computer skills.
>   **Miss Kizlet**: Upload her anyway, splice her a computer skills package.

So, the 2 criteria to select someone is being clever and having computer skills. But somehow, they could add computer skill, probably only if a subject was worth the hassle.

We don't have the technical details on how the computer skills package is *spliced*, but my guess is that they added the package to the signal as it's downloaded, just before it's saved to the cloud. So they don't have to use additional bandwidth to do the modification, the doctor just retrieved the modified data.

Why they'd give her the enhancement first? It may be a technical limitation, maybe they cannot modify a consciousness once it's saved on the cloud. Anyway, they don't worry about download reversal before the Doctor did it as they are surprised when it happens and state that such thing is possible, *in theory*.

Comment: Idle question: how did you know the names "Alexei" and "Miss Kizlet"? I.e. were these used in the episode (and I am even less observant than I thought), or did you look them up somewhere?

Comment: @Martha I checked [tardis.wikia episode wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bells_of_Saint_John_%28TV_story%29). But the quotes come from the subtitle of the episodes. As a non native English speaker, I always turn on the subtitles for Doctor Who. I made a check and they are explicitly called by theirs names on several occasion in the episode.

Comment: But still the question remains. Why give her those skills? What would those skills have been used for, once she was in the cloud? And why take her in the first place, if her skills were not up to standard? My guess is we're going to see more of this mysterious "client", this great intelligence, later in the series.

Comment: Well, if the Great Intelligence was "eating" the people in the cloud to be happy, the computer skills could be as simple as a flavor that the Great Intelligence likes to eat. Like putting ketchup on fries. Alternately, they might enhance the Great Intelligence when he consumes the person, like putting protein powder in an energy shake to bulk up at the gym.

Answer (score 1):

As of the start of season 8, Clara has not used those powers since that episode where she got them, but a version of Clara did do a super hack on the Daleks in "Asylum of the Daleks", a hack which impressed the hell out of the Doctor himself, which aired earlier.  And since there is a connection between all the Claras, maybe giving her magically superior skills was written in for that purpose.

I don't think there's a cleverer explanation than that right now.

Answer (score -3):

The bad guys didn't give Clara the hacker powers.  It hasn't been made very clear yet but it appears to be a piece of innate computer knowledge that Clara brought back with her when the Doctor pulled back the part of her that had already been uploaded to the Wifi.  There is another episode from last season that included Clara and the Daleks in the future where she puts those hacker skills to good use.

Comment: Sorry, but they did explicitly say that they *added* hacker powers to Clara. See my answer.

Comment: @DavRob60 While they clearly did state they were adding computer skills, I'm not sure BBlake is wrong here. It's pretty clear that Clara's skills went far beyond what the rest of the team there had, even though it was demonstrated that their abilities were also "hacked". And Clara *did* show amazing, and somewhat unexplained, computer skills... hacking the Daleks is *not* something a naturally talented human hacker would be expected to be able to do.

Comment: @Beofett That's because she is really cleaver. It's something to have knowledge, it's something else to use it and expand upon it. The point is that they "spliced her a computer skills package", it's not a "piece of innate computer knowledge that Clara brought back with her".

Comment: I have a feeling we may learn more about her hacking abilities in later episodes. It may be that the splicing triggered something deeper in her.  It may be that her being converted in the previous episode I referenced may have done something similar. I think it's too soon to say one or another for certain.

Comment: The Clara who hacked the Daleks was a different incarnation, with different life experiences, and thus different specific skills.

Comment: @Martha I don't believe we know that for sure, yet.

Comment: @Martha it might be this Clara later. This might be how she got so good then. There is precedent for women living backwards to the Dr, and dying the first time he meets her / last time she meets him. Although doing it more than once is a neat trick.

Comment: I must have missed that line from the episode.  Need to watch it again.

Comment: @KateGregory: I don't think Dalek!Clara recognized the Doctor, did she?

Comment: Also, people dying on the Doctor and then being restored is getting a bit old. I thought we were done with that after we left Rory. Oh well. Still looking forward to tonight's episode!

Comment: @Martha you seem to be assuming that either the Claras are completely unrelated, or that they are a single person living in a specific, albeit nonstandard, continuity (which somehow includes dying multiple times), with no room for other possibilities. There's a lot of assumption here, with nothing (yet) to back it up with beyond speculation.

Comment: @Beofett: I don't think I'm making any huge or unwarranted assumptions. Clearly, the Claras are related in some way. Equally clearly, they're not the same person at different points in her life: each incarnation meets the Doctor anew, and knows nothing whatsoever about the other incarnations. And that's without even going near her multiple deaths. (I think the *Doctor* assumed governess-Clara was Dalek-Clara at an earlier point in her life, which is why he was so surprised when she died.)

Comment: @Martha The assumption seems to be that, beyond the points you outlined just now (which I agree with), is that there is absolutely no carry over in skills or abilities from one Martha to another. The only point I'm trying to make is that everyone is assuming that because an intent was stated to "add a computer skills pack" (during the process of a *partial*, and ultimately failed, upload), it is given as fact that that is the sole explanation for becoming an instant super-hacker. Personally, I think that's quite a leap.

Comment: @Beofett, except the episode points out that pre-upload Clara knew very little about computers - she couldn't even fix her Wifi connection, nevermind anything even remotely hacker-ish. Yes, she's intelligent, but intelligence without knowledge isn't immediately useful.

Comment: @Martha That's kind of my point. She's listed as "very clever", then given a standard computer skills package. She then hacks into a computer system developed by a group that, at a minimum, can "hack" into someone's IQ, and most likely was designed (at least in part) by an alien intelligence. That implies there may be a bit more happening here than just "computer skills" + "very clever".

Comment: “There is another episode from last season that included Clara and the Daleks in the future where she puts those hacker skills to good use.” SPOILER ALERT: I don’t think the Clara in *Asylum of the Daleks* used hacker skills of her own; she was able to hack into the Dalek asylum’s computers because, by that point, she *was* a Dalek.

Comment: They've already done the "Meeting in different temporal order" thing with River Song. I think Clara is something quite different. Clones? Naah, they just did that one (sorta), too. Versions from different dimensions? Nope, THAT's been done recently (well, within the last ten years, anyway. For Brits, that's recent) as well. A Literally split personality?

Comment: Man... Clara hacked the Daleks because she's _cleaver_. That's got to be one of the funniest typos ever! :D